To identify the following SMD component marked "365 P2303 982"
I need help in identifying this SMD component.

Which has the following marking code "365 P2303 982" which is a 16-pin component top - 7 pins, bottom -7, left and right each pin and its present in the power line. Mostly it seems like a power management IC (DC- DC converter).



Sure will redraft the questions thanks for the guide.

What are the dimensions of the chip? I'm starting to think that this is an unusual QFN-16 form factor.

Probably something from ST Microelectronics  https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/motion-sensor-ics/7167059

Hello @colin, thank you for your reply. I'll provide the dimensions.

Hello @vivier, thank you for your reply, will check the line.

It's a Bosch BMI088 6-axis motion sensor.


(Source: lcsc.com)

thank you for your valuable time & response.
